# Push objects in to Filtered JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript

Given this example how can I push each result found by the filter into the obj rather than reset it once for each item found by the filter?

The filter grabs the first result from the filter and sets obj[0] to that value. Suppose I have 10 results from the filter how do I append the values to obj rather than set it to a single value.  I thought I would need to use push.

```
var obj = array.filter(function ( obj ) {
    return obj.name === name;
})[0];
```

Comment: can you describe the question more?

Comment: By not taking only the first item in the filter result?

Comment: I added more description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply remove the zero index from the filtered result;

```
var obj = array.filter(function ( obj ) {
    return obj.name === name;
}); //now obj has all the filtered items
```

"The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function." [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**But** if you want to append/concatenate filetered results to another existing array then you are looking for the `.concat` function

```
obj.concat(array.filter(function ( obj ) {
    return obj.name === name;
})); //obj is an existing array
```